# Developer permissions by default for the members of GitLab

Tags: permissions, gitlab

We have a wiki for documentation for all the members of the company. Because of LDAP authentication, anyone in my company can sign in to GitLab and a new GitLab user account associated with this user is created.

The wiki is located in a **project** inside a **group** like this:

https://gitlab.com/somegroup/nameoftheproject/

Group visibility: **internal**
Project visibility: **internal**

When a user logs into GitLab, he can see the wiki pages but he cannot edit them unless I manually invite him through the members tab and give him  **developer** permission.

I would like that all the users from the company (hundreds) have developer permissions by default (instead of guest) when accessing the wiki so that they can edit it. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: For internal projects : "Any logged in user will have Guest permissions on the repository." (https://gitlab.com/help/public_access/public_access).

Is there a way to change the default user access level setting?

Comment: I have a similar issue, when users request access to my project, the default permission the GUI shows to grant access is `Developer`, but I want it to be `Guest`. We don't have many developers, and it just seems like an accident waiting to happen.